# Xtext define number of occurrence

Tags: xtext

Being new to Xtext I would like to know how to define the upper and lower boundaries regarding the occurrence of a letter.

I know of the following expressions / operators

- exactly one (the default, no operator)
- one or none (operator ?)
- any (zero or more, operator *)
- one or more (operator +)

Given the examples

```
<IS123A4>

<IS12>

<ISB123455>
```

how do I describe the grammar for the rule that after "IS" 1-25 alphanumeric letters may appear.

Currently, I have

```
`terminal ISCONCEPTAME : '<IS' ALPHANUM ALPHANUM? ALPHANUM? ALPHANUM?.....'>';`
`terminal ALPHANUM: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|INT);`
```

However, I am not sure if it is the right way to do it. I was thinking about something like

```
`terminal ISCONCEPTAME : '<IS' ALPHANUM{1,25} '>';`
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: did you consider using this a validation instead of a grammar. that might give you the chance to give better error messages. or are you parsing a column based file